# VB6/COM Interop: where do these events come from?

Tags: c#, vb6, com-interop

I have written a COM-visible class library in C# 4.0 which I'm consuming with VB6. The thing works, only if I open up the VB6 *object browser* and look at the members exposed, I'm seeing an event for each and every single exposed member... **but the C# code doesn't define any of them**.

Is this normal? Am I doing something wrong?

```
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IMyClass))]
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    public void DoSomething(string someParam)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public interface IMyClass
{
    void DoSomething(string someParam);
}
```

The assembly is signed with a strong name key and `AssemblyInfo.cs` has the `[assembly: ComVisible(true)]` attribute set, but I'm not sure it has anything to do with the issue.

When I look at the object browser in VB6, I would be expecting to see `DoSomething(string)` as a member of `MyClass`, *and I do*, however I'm *also* seeing an event with a matching signature for every exposed method, like `Event DoSomething(someParam As String)` as a member of `MyClass`.

Even more puzzling (to me at least), properties also have a "matching" event (can only tell from the little lightning icon though) - if `MyClass` defined a property like this:

```
public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
```

The VB6 object browser would say the "event" is defined as `Property SomeProperty As String`, which leaves me flabbergasted - how does a "property" 1) gets duplicated and 2) the duplicate gets displayed with an "event" icon in the object browser? The same applies to get-only properties, which have their read-only "property/event" counterpart.

Where do these events come from and how do I get rid of them?

**UPDATE** An image is worth a thousand words:

[image: COM Interop - bogus events]

**UPDATE** The *wrong thing* was the `ComSourceInterfaces` attribute which was mistakenly being used in place of a `ComDefaultInterface` attribute. Swapping the former for the latter gives the expected result:

[image: COM Interop - correct members]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By passing `typeof(IMyClass)` as an argument to the ComSourceInterface attribute you're saying that everything in the IMyClass is an event.

If you don't want an event interface for your class remove the ComSourceInterface attribute.

If you **do** want to expose events from your C# class to VB then do the following:

When you create a COM visible class you'll also want to create an interface that defines just the event handlers for your class. Your class should be decorated with the COMSourceInterface specifying your event handler interface and should define your events and implement the event handler interface. See [How To: Raise Events Handled by a COM sink](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3(v=vs.100).aspx) for another example.

```
[GuidAttribute("1A585C4D-3371-48dc-AF8A-AFFECC1B0967") ]
[InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface MyEvents
{
    void ConnectedEvent(string state);
}


[ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(MyEvents))]
public class MyClass
{
    public event Action<string> ConnectedEvent;

    public MyClass() { }

    public void DoSomething(string state)
    { 
        if (ConnectedEvent != null)
            ConnectedEvent(state);
    }
}
```

See also: [Murat's Corner: Exposing COM Events](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murat/archive/2008/11/20/exposing-com-events-c.aspx)

Comment: I have never exposed a C# event to COM, thanks for this post I'll certainly come back to it when I need to do so, ...but I can't accept it as an answer since *there's no event anywhere in the C# code*... and the question is about where the heck those COM/VB6 events are coming from; I don't think an upvote is warranted for *this* answer (as is) on *this* question. But this would be an awesome answer if I were asking about exposing C# events to COM/VB6; if you're going to edit your answer, please edit your post by appending to it; it's still valuable information, though a little off-topic.

Comment: @retailcoder but you did, with the `ComSourceInterfaces` attribute. This tells tlbexport that your object can source events given that interface.

Comment: @retailcoder The implication in my answer was that you've specified an event interface by using the ComSourceInterface attribute. Remove it if you don't want to expose event connection points.

Comment: FYI, the first link has died :)

Answer (score 9):

You are basically finding out that there isn't anything special about events in COM.  Like anything in COM, events are backed by an interface.  The only thing special about an interface that specifies event methods is that it is marked with the [source] attribute in the type library.  Which is all that the [ComSourceInterfaces] attribute does, recognized by Tlbexp.exe when it generates the type library.

Nor is there anything particularly special about properties in COM.  They work just like they do in .NET, they are implemented with *methods*.  A getter and a setter method.

So VB6 looks at your type library and is happy about a class that has events since it has an interface with the [source] attribute.  And is happy about that interface having methods, all they can ever have, so it assumes those are the methods that run when the event is raised.  It isn't otherwise smart enough to recognize that those methods are also the accessors for a property, it assumes that the type library author knows what he's doing.

Events are called "connection points" in COM.  Google IConnectionPoint to learn more about it.  If you ever create a WinRT component with custom event accessors then you'll also see that COM events have little in common with .NET events.

Anyhoo, the workaround is simple, only use [ComSourceInterface] when you raise events.

Comment: And when the class derives from a generic type, ...that was why the *ComSourceInterfaceAttribute*...wasn't expecting this "side-effect"! Thanks for the explanation, I learned something today!

Comment: COM doesn't support generics, only concrete classes without a type argument can be [ComVisible].

Comment: Ah! There's my mistake: I mixed-up `[ComSourceInterface]` and `[ComDefaultInterface]` - "Type library exporter encountered a type that derives from a generic type and is not marked as [...] ClassInterfaceType.None [...] Consider [...] exposing an explicit interface as the default interface to COM using the [ComDefaultInterface] attribute." ...I know COM doesn't support generics, I wrote "when a class *derives from* a generic type".